# Typescript for defineMessages in react-intl package

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-intl

The `react-intl` package has a `defineMessages` method for defining the messages for translation in the format:

```
const messages = defineMessages({
    'account.activation.error': {
        id: 'account.activation.error',
        defaultMessage: 'This activation link is not valid.',
    },
});
```

I can't find the type definitions for this package, so how would you define this using TypeScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `react-intl` package is shipped with it's [own type definitions](https://github.com/formatjs/formatjs/blob/6b7ad95/packages/react-intl/package.json#L128). So you don't have to look for external ones. You may install the package and open `node_modules/react-intl/index.d.ts` file in your code editor. Or use `Go to definition` functionality on `defineMessages` function if it's available in your IDE.

[playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMyZVm)

Comment: Why do I get this is they are already declared by `react-intl`? TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ 'account.activation.error': { id: string; defaultMessage: string; }; ... 210 more ...;